# Can I get input field object from range selector using java? Highchart

Tags: java, highcharts

Is there any API to get range selector input fields from highcharts using java?

moxiegroup API provides only set methods, but I want to get Input field.

I am talking about fields that represents on screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: in **JS version** of Highcharts these timestamps are placed in `chart.rangeSelector.minInput.HCTime` and  `chart.rangeSelector.maxInput.HCTime` properties. **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/0gecvwaj/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: `yourChartObject.getXAxis().getExtremes();`